How do I update the DOM using JavaScript fetch method to filter user data from API?
I am looking to GET Data from API and display in HTML page using JavaScript fetch function.
The JavaScript codes are detailed below. I can read the console.log of the user data from API. However, nothing is displayed on the HTML page as expected.

    <script>
      fetch('https://dummyjson.com/user')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data));
    </script>


I can't seem to figure out what is missing.

I have added a loop function to retrieve and filter the API data and insert the result into HTML tag as detailed below:
    <script>
      fetch('https://dummyjson.com/user')
        .then(result => {
          return result.json();
        })
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .then(data => {
          data.forEach(user => {
            const show = `<p>${user.firstName}</p>`;
            let html = document.querySelector('item');
            html.insertAdjacentHTML('after begin', show);
          });
        });
    </script>



Expected result should have been the first names (firstName) of all the user.
When the code runs, output does not display the expected result in the HTML page.
The console log does not show any errors. Simply a blank page.
Complete Code Below:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <style>
          body {
        background: transparent;
        color: #2c0493;
        padding: 44px;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100vh;
        align-items: center;
        font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen,
          Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
      }

      h3,
      h2 {
        margin: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2 id="header">GET Data from API</h2>
    <h3>And display in HTML with JavaScript</h3>
    <hr />
    <div id="item"></div>
    <script>
      fetch('https://dummyjson.com/user')
        .then(result => {
          return result.json()
        })
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .then(data => {
          data.forEach(user => {
            const show = `<p>${user.firstName}</p>`
            let html = document.querySelector('item')
            html.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', show)
          });
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>


More Screenshots here:

Expected output:


Nobody seems to have pointed out it's not html.insertAdjacentHTML('after begin', show); it's html.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', show);

@JaromandaX - Yes, thank you for pointing that out. I did initially Use 'after begin' with a space.  However I noticed and corrected it as I tried to check through and debug my code.
I have updated the code with all the recommendations.
Two-months in, I have learnt a lot.  Highly appreciated.

Firstly, lets address the issues in your code

.then(data => console.log(data)) means the next .then receives undefined as the argument
the data is not an array, the array is data.users
when getting an id in .querySelector, since it's CSS syntax, you need a # in the selector, e.g. #item
in .insertAdjacentHTML the first argument is one of beforebegin|afterbegin|beforeend|afterend ... there is no space in this value

One thing to note, since you use .afterbegin the list will be shown in reverse order to the data you receive - that may be your intention, if not, you would use beforeend in .insertAdjacentHTML
Fixing your code, so it works:


fetch('https://dummyjson.com/user')
  .then(result => result.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  }) // 1. keep the data flowing in the chain
  .then(data => {
    data.users.forEach(user => { // 2. data.users is the array you are after
      const show = `<p>${user.firstName}</p>`;
      let html = document.querySelector('#item'); // 3. note the `#`
      html.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', show); // 4. no space in afterbegin
      // note, this will display users in reverse order w.r.t. data.users
    });
  })
<p id="item"></p>



Let's do modern version, note the async function would not be needed in a <script type="module"> since that allows top level await


async function getData() {
  const target = document.querySelector('#item');
  const result = await fetch('https://dummyjson.com/user');
  const data = await result.json();
  console.log(data);
  // remove the this     .reverse() below if you didn't mean to reverse the order
  const html = data.users.reverse().map(({firstName}) =>`<p>${firstName}</p>`).join("");
  target.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', html);
}
getData();
<p id="item"></p>




Code updated. Now working perfectly as expected.
I have changed the querySelector to : getElementsById.
I see the case:  need to select a single element in this case.
Also will be reading up on the Async function.

You do array foreach but not on the correct array.
should be something like:
fetch('https://dummyjson.com/user')
  .then(result => {
    return result.json()
  })
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .then(data => {
    data.users.forEach(user => {
      const show = `<p>${user.firstName}</p>`
      let html = document.querySelector('item')
      html.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', show)
    });
  });


You've failed to address at least 3 other issues in the OP's code ... the main one being what the result of .then(data => console.log(data)) would be :p

According to the querySelector() documentation:

The Document method querySelector() returns the first Element within
the document that matches the specified CSS selector, or group of CSS
selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.
Blockquote

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector
You can use getElementById() to achieve the desired result with something like
let html = document.getElementById("item");
html.innerHTML = "<p>whatever you want<p>"

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Other than the 4 other errors in the OP's code that you didn't address, your code would only show the last element of the forEach loop

@PekosoG  - Yes, getElementById is preferred.
